# RFID-RC522 not reading all cards

Tags: arduino, rfid

I have used Arduino UNO with RFID-RC522

I'm using https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid library

Wiring :
`3.3 V -> 3.3 V`
`RST  -> 9`
`GND  -> GND`

`MISO -> 12`
`MOSI -> 11`
`SCK  -> 13`
`SDA  -> 10`

Only one card is working which came with RC-522. I have purchased 10 other cards. None of these working.
Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that there are various RFID standards which use different protocols and/or frequencies. If you have a card that is not compatible with your reader it will not work.

RC522 operates at 13.56MHz. If you purchased 125kHz e.g. transponders they cannot communicate!

Answer (score 0):

Remove LED from RC522 board. My new MINI RFID-RC522 not read any card before i unsolder LED.

Or take more power about 3.6V-4.6V. My "big" works better with extra power. Maybe because of LED too.